# Get error when test with jest. Error is Converting circular structure to JSON in moment.js line

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, momentjs

I am using angular and jest. My error happens when i add moment.js in code.

my import in my component

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

Error line

```
const date = moment(new Date(2023, 1, 1)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

In spec tests i just call method where this line is located

```
component.getAll();
```

Full error

```
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor '_Zone'
    |     property '_zoneDelegate' -> object with constructor '_ZoneDelegate'
    --- property 'zone' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)

  at messageParent (../../node_modules/jest-runner/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/messageParent.js:29:19)
```

getDate() function where moment is calling

```
getDate() {
    this.selectedYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.selectedMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    this.selectedMonthData = moment(
      new Date(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth - 1, 1)
    ).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    this.months = months;
    this.years = [];
    for (let year = 2000; year <= this.selectedYear + 1; year++) {
      this.years.push({
        value: year,
        title: year.toString(),
      });
    }
}
```

getAll() function calls getDate function

```
getAll(): void {
    ...
    this.getDate();
    ...
}
```

Hm... I also get warning

```
Calling "moment" will crash at run-time because it's an import namespace object, not a function [call-import-namespace]
```

Maybe is it reason of my crash?

getAll

```
getAll(): void {
    Promise.all([
      this.settingsService.getItem(
        "group",
        false
      ),
      this.settingsService.getItem(
        "serialNumber",
        false
      ),
      this.settingsService.getItem("shifts"),
      this.settingsService.getItem("version")
    ]).then(
      (res) => {
         this.settings = {
         group: res[0] as boolean,
         serialNumber: res[1] as boolean,
         shifts: (res[2] as number[]) || [],
         version: res[3] as number,
       };       
       
       this.getDate();
    });
}
```

Comment: Share full error from jest. Also share code of your relevant sections.

Comment: Can you add the full code of `getAll()` function?

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris i posted answer for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount desicion of it.

in test:

```
component.getDate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(null);
```

The same thing you can do with any function